# How to overcome fear to fail squat?

Tags: squats, injury

If one is it to fail the low bar squat, the way to fail it is given as you remove the hand grip and walk forward. , I have a feeling that I'll have an injury because I can't see the weight I'm dropping. Could some advice be given on how to overcome this?

Comment: I'm guessing using safety rails is not an option?

Comment: Sort of is , but may not always be available as the single squat rack can get busy sometimes in my gym @DeeV

Answer (score 1):

Practice bailing out of the squat with lower weights that you can handle safely and build up to your working weight.

Set up that squat rack with safety rails when you can and practice bailing out with the empty barbel a few times, once you're confident add some weight. This way you'll be prepared when it happens.

Or just don't go to failure when you can't do it safely. Squat with lighter weights for more reps or stop with more reps in reserve and do more sets for the same volume. I wouldn't go doing singles and doubles for PR if I can't safely fail.